# Maths in a while loop causing random negative numbers

Tags: bash, math

So I have done this in both python and bash, and the code I am about to post probably has a world of things wrong with it but it is generally very basic and I cannot see a reason that it would cause this 'bug' which I will explain soon.. I have done the same in Python, but much more professionally and cleanly and it also causes this error (at some point, the maths generates a negative number, which makes no sense.)

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ];
do

zero=0
ARRAY=()
ARRAY2=()

first=`command to generate a list of numbers`
sleep 1
second=`command to generate a list of numbers`

# so now we have two data sets, 1 second between the capture of each.

for i in $first;
do
ARRAY+=($i)
done

for i in $second;
do
ARRAY2+=($i)
done

for (( c=$zero; c<=${#ARRAY2[@]}; c++ ))
do
expr ${ARRAY2[$c]} - ${ARRAY[$c]}
done

ARRAY=()
ARRAY2=()
zero=0
c=0
first=``
second=``
math=''

done
```

So the script grabs a set of data, waits 1 second, grabs it again, does math on the two sets to get the difference, that difference is printed. It's very simple, and I have done it elegantly in Python too - no matter how I would do it every now and then, could be anywhere from 3 loops in to 30 loops in, we will get negative numbers.. like so:

> START 0 0 0 0 0 19 10 563 0
>   -34 19 14 2 0
>   -1302 1198
>   -532 639
>   -1078 1119 1 0 0
>   -843 33 880 0 5
>   -8
>   -13508 8773 4541 988 181
>   -12
>   -205 217
>   -9 7 1
>   -360 303 60 1 0 0
>   -12
>   -96 98 3
>   -870 904
>   -130
>   -2105 2264 6
>   -3084 1576 1650
>   -939 971
>   -2249 1150 1281
>
> ### -693 9 513 142 76 expr: syntax error

Please help, I simply can't find anything about this.

Sample OUTPUT as requested:

```
ARRAY1 OUTPUT
1 15 1 25 25 1 2 1 3541 853 94567 42 5 1 351 51 1 11 1 13 7 14 12 3999 983 5 1938 3 8287 40 1 1 1 5253 706 1 1 1 1 5717 3 50 1 85 100376 17334 4655 1 1345 2 1 16 1777 1 3 38 23 8 32 47 781 947 1 1 206 9 1 3 2 81 2602 7 158 1 1 43 91 1 120 6589 6 2534 1092 1 6014 7 2 2 37 1 1 1 80 2 1 1270 15448 66 1 10238 1 10794 16061 4 1 1 1 9754 5617 1123 926 3 24 10 16
ARRAY2 OUTPUT
1 15 1 25 25 1 2 1 3555 859 95043 42 5 1 355 55 1 11 1 13 7 14 12 4015 987 5 1938 3 8335 40 1 1 1 5280 706 1 1 1 1 5733 3 50 1 85 100877 17396 4691 1 1353 2 1 16 1782 1 3 38 23 8 32 47 787 947 1 1 206 9 1 3 2 81 2602 7 159 1 1 43 91 1 120 6869 6 2534 1092 1 6044 7 2 2 37 1 1 1 80 2 1 1270 15563 66 1 10293 1 10804 16134 4 1 1 1 9755 5633 1135 928 3 24 10 16
START
```

Comment: I did. It is bash, and it is in the tags. I am new so if I am wrong please do correct me.

Comment: The obvious explanation is that at some point the value in `ARRAY2` is less than the value in `ARRAY1`. Are you absolutely _sure_ that isn't happening?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too! I'm sure it isn't because every value 1 second after is either the same or has to have grown, it simply cannot go down.

Comment: Please print out `ARRAY` and `ARRAY2` and show them here!

Comment: Added sample of array and array2 to the question!

Comment: it appears you are trying to access too many positions in the array.  It is zero based, which means for an array of size 3, you can only access [0], [1], and [2].  your code contains `<=` in the loop, which means [3] would also be accessed...BAD!  I don't know how bash would handle this, but in C/C++, this behavior would simply be grabbing the next chunk of memory.  You may be reading in random variables for other programs.  **TLDR:** change `<=` to `<`

Comment: I appreciate your advice and I already considered that to be an issue - following your advice does not help, furthermore changing the line so that we change c<=${#ARRAY[@]} to c<=40 or c<40 (I know the array will be well over 40 objects in size) it does not help, still get the bug.

Comment: To back that up, I ran a test, I set it to do maths on objects 0-40 and printed the array size before doing that. Here we see: START
ARRAY SIZE IS 58
START
0
0
18
9
572
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
173
6
0
26
0
35
0
38
0
0
504
21
26
5
-371
372
-3
-57
-103
-235
375
-73
88
-330
180
166
-1
-26
-2280

Comment: Note that you can set your arrays directly: `ARRAY=( $( command to generate a list of numbers ) )`.

Comment: Thank you for that chepner, though I am aware this is dirty code with some not-so-best practices.

Comment: You really need to print out ARRAY and ARRAY2 in the case where you find a negative number. (Although if it happens within 30 iterations, you could just print them out every time.) Printing them just once is not going to prove that elements of ARRAY2 are always greater than corresponding elements in ARRAY.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in [Russell Uhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2415755/russell-uhl)'s comment above. Your loop runs one time to many(this is your code):

```
for (( c=$zero; c<=${#ARRAY2[@]}; c++ ))
do
        expr ${ARRAY2[$c]} - ${ARRAY[$c]}
done
```

To fix, you need to change the test condition from `c <= ${#ARRAY2[@]}` to `c < ${#ARRAY2[@]}`:

```
for (( c=$zero; c < ${#ARRAY2[@]}; c++ ))
do
        echo $((${ARRAY2[$c]} - ${ARRAY[$c]}))
done
```

I've also changed the expr to use arithmetic evaluation builtin `$((...))`.

The test script (`sum.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
zero=0
ARRAY=()
ARRAY2=()

first="1 15 1 25 25 1 2 1 3541 853 94567 42 5 1 351 51 1 11 1 13 7 14 12 3999 983 5 1938 3 8287 40 1 1 1 5253 706 1 1 1 1 5717 3 50 1 85 100376 17334 4655 1 1345 2 1 16 1777 1 3 38 23 8 32 47 7
second="1 15 1 25 25 1 2 1 3555 859 95043 42 5 1 355 55 1 11 1 13 7 14 12 4015 987 5 1938 3 8335 40 1 1 1 5280 706 1 1 1 1 5733 3 50 1 85 100877 17396 4691 1 1353 2 1 16 1782 1 3 38 23 8 32 47

for i in $first; do
    ARRAY+=($i)
done

# Alternately as chepner suggested:
ARRAY2=($second)

for (( c=$zero; c < ${#ARRAY2[@]}; c++ )); do
    echo -n $((${ARRAY2[$c]} - ${ARRAY[$c]})) " "
done
```

Running it:

```
samveen@precise:/tmp$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.2.25(1)-release
samveen@precise:/tmp$ bash sum.sh
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  14  6  476  0  0  0  4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  16  4  0  0  0  48  0  0  0  0  27  0  0  0  0  0  16  0  0  0  0  501  62  36  0  8  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  280  0  0  0  0  30  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  115  0  0  55  0  10  73  0  0  0  0  1  16  12  2  0  0  0  0
```

EDIT:
* Added improvements from suggestions in comments.

Comment: Thank you for your help but as I confirmed above and have just tested your solution, this does not work. I feel like I am going crazy :(

Comment: @leejez Adding the test script with your test input and test output for your consideration.

Comment: You are assuming the problem occurs 100% of the time, as I stated it happens every now and then during a loop. Sorry but this doesn't help me.

Comment: @leejez Change `expr` to `echo -n " "` and run your program again. That should give you debug info on where it goes wrong.

Comment: After further testing I cannot find a solution. The closest anyone came was this advice but I feel it was too hastily provided as the be all end all answer. I already knew of all of the scenarios (ARRAY1 size was smaller than ARRAY2, vice versa) - and any changes made to account for this still fail to fix the error. Hell I have even proven that ignoring array size entirely and working with a set 0-20 loop (the array will always be larger than 40) causes errors. Not sure it is and will probably give up, this will force me to make a really dirty solution somewhere down the line I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to be when the two arrays don't have the same size. It's easy to reproduce that syntax error -- one of the operands for the minus operator is an empty string:

```
$ a=5; b=3; expr $a - $b
2
$ a=""; b=3; expr $a - $b
expr: syntax error
$ a=5; b=""; expr $a - $b
expr: syntax error
$ a=""; b=""; expr $a - $b
-
```

Try

```
ARRAY=( $(command to generate a list of numbers) )
sleep 1
ARRAY2=( $(command to generate a list of numbers) )

if (( ${#ARRAY[@]} != ${#ARRAY2[@]} )); then
    echo "error: different size arrays!"
    echo "ARRAY: ${#ARRAY[@]} (${ARRAY[*]})"
    echo "ARRAY2: ${#ARRAY2[@]} (${ARRAY2[*]})"
fi
```

---

"The error occurs whenever the first array is smaller than the second" -- of course. You're looping from 0 to the array size of ARRAY2. When ARRAY has fewer elements, you'll eventually try to access an index that does not exist in the array. When you try to reference an unset variable, bash gives you the empty string.

```
$ a=(1 2 3)
$ b=(4 5 6 7)
$ i=2; expr ${a[i]} - ${b[i]}
-3
$ i=3; expr ${a[i]} - ${b[i]}
expr: syntax error
```

Comment: Funnily enough I was sat here giving this another go and did a bunch of fun tests.. I tried to get the lowest array size and use that - surely that would make sure we were never accessing an object outside of the array and thus causing an error? Nope. That made no sense, so I took it a step further and reversed it, first I checked which is the lowest, then defined that as the highest - Nope. I'm still speechless - but here is some more information. The error occurs whenever the first array is smaller than the second. Examples below..

Comment: The lowest of 28 and 29 is 28
4
1
40
0
0
0
4
2
2
52
5
0
10
0
0
0
5
3
4
-21
25
-59
55
14
-129
194
2

The lowest of 29 and 29 is 29
3
0
48
0
0
1
6
4
2
47
93
0
42
2
1
0
1
3
3
0
5
5
11
8
3
75
0
0

The lowest of 30 and 32 is 30
2
0
65
0
0
2
0
6
6
5
51
16
0
72
0
1
0
-45
16
0
33
-48
34
-155
-61
137
-317
55
447

I'm sure I can come up with some weird solution.. thanks everyone for pushing me in this direction at best you can :) I'll post the solution when I find it for sure.